# Android, запуск процесса, обрабатывающего выход второго процесса

Tags: android, процесс

```
 proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"ls"});
```

Используя код выше можно запустить ls, также можно запустить процесс с аргументами.
Но как запустить что-то вроде этого?

```
ls | egrep "init|sys"
```

Это явно не сработает:

```
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"ls","|","egrep","\"init|sys\""});
```

Comment: На большом SO [рекомендуют](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5928316/5661663) оформлять все команды в однострочный скрипт, и запускать, как параметр для `sh -c`.

Comment: Пробовал. Error running exec(). Command: [/bin/sh, -c, logcat | grep something] Working Directory: null Environment: null